# What is the efficient method to compare two lists of class-objects

Tags: python, list, oop, compare

I have two lists of class-objects. listA and listB. the list are initialized by reading data from two different file. Please assume that several (large amount) of objects were created.
Each object has several attributes.
The lists are quite big.
1) I would like to find the most efficient way to iterate and compare these two lists and find out which attribute/s is/are different per object.
2) should I use other object collect than a list?

```
listA = []
listB = []
class refA (object):
    def __init__(self, xCoord, yCoord, Name):
        self.xCoord = xCoord
        self.yCoord = yCoord
        self.name = name
        listA.append(self)

class refB (object):
    def __init__(self, xCoord, yCoord, Name):
        self.xCoord = xCoord
        self.yCoord = yCoord
        self.name = name
        listB.append(self)
```

Comment: Are you comparing every object in `listA` with every object of `listB`. Do you *control/* the classes? Can you add an `__equ__` method?

Comment: Can you just reduce the two lists to a single `set()` and use a single class with a `__eq__` function? I say this because both classes have what I assume is the same data.

Comment: What is your desired outcome for 1)? Do you want only to have a list of unique objects or do you need something else?

Comment: I want to compare every object of listA with every object of listB. Basically, I want to find if the object: A) Does not exist in listB. B) Partially exist in listB by the equality of xCoord and yCoord but some other record/s is are differ so I would like to identify which records are different.Generally I can implement some kind of equality function but the main thing I worry about is the execution time.so this is what I'm asking - what is the most efficient way to go over each object from listA and comapre it with each object of listB? if the list of object is not efficient -> what would be?